# Gravar data de inclusão usando entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework

Eu acredito que houve uma interpretação equivocada, estou postando o código para que seja melhor entendido.
Eu estou usando um projeto para o meu Repositório EF é dentro dele eu tenho:

Observe a dúvida em //empresaSalvar.DATA_IND = DateTime.Now; isso é possivel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Projeto.Financeiro.Dominio;
using Projeto.Financeiro.Dominio.contrato;

namespace Projeto.Financeiro.RepositorioEF
{
    public class EmpresaRepositorioEF : IRepositorio<tb_empresa>
    {

        private readonly Contexto contexto;

        public EmpresaRepositorioEF()
        {
            contexto = new Contexto();
        }

        //salvar ou altera o registro
        public void SalvarRegistro(tb_empresa entidade)
        {
            if (entidade.IDEMPRESA > 0)
            {
                var empresaAlterar = contexto.Empresa.First(x => x.IDEMPRESA == entidade.IDEMPRESA);
                empresaAlterar.RAZAO_SOCIAL = entidade.RAZAO_SOCIAL;
                empresaAlterar.ENDERECO = entidade.ENDERECO;
                empresaAlterar.BAIRRO = entidade.BAIRRO;
                empresaAlterar.CIDADE = entidade.CIDADE;
                empresaAlterar.IMAGEM_LOGO = entidade.IMAGEM_LOGO;
                empresaAlterar.STATUS = entidade.STATUS;
                empresaAlterar.DATA_ALT = entidade.DATA_ALT;
            }
            else
            {
                //empresaSalvar.DATA_IND = DateTime.Now; isso é possivel
                contexto.Empresa.Add(entidade);
            }

            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }

        //excluir o registro
        public void ExcluirRegistro(tb_empresa entidade)
        {

            var empresaExcluir = contexto.Empresa.First(x => x.IDEMPRESA == entidade.IDEMPRESA);
            contexto.Set<tb_empresa>().Remove(empresaExcluir);
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }

        //listar por id
        public tb_empresa ListarPorId(string id)
        {
            int idInt;
            Int32.TryParse(id, out idInt);
            return contexto.Empresa.First(x => x.IDEMPRESA == idInt);
        }

        //listar todos
        public IEnumerable<tb_empresa> ListarTodos()
        {
            return contexto.Empresa;
        }


    }
}
```

minha Entidade

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Projeto.Financeiro.RepositorioEF
{
     public interface IEntidade
     {
          DateTime DATA_ALTERACAO { get; set; }
          DateTime DATA_INCLUSAO { get; set; }
     }
}
```

meu Contexto:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Projeto.Financeiro.Dominio;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;

namespace Projeto.Financeiro.RepositorioEF
{
    public class Contexto:DbContext
    {

        public  Contexto() : base("BancoDados")
        {

        }


        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            var Contexto = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

            IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> objectStateEntries =
            from e in Contexto.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified)
            where
                e.IsRelationship == false &&
                e.Entity != null &&
                typeof(IEntidade).IsAssignableFrom(e.Entity.GetType())
            select e;

            var dataAtual = DateTime.Now;

            foreach (var entry in objectStateEntries)
            {
                dynamic entityBase = entry.Entity;

                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added || entityBase.DataCriacao == DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    entityBase.DATA_INCLUSAO = dataAtual;

                }

                entityBase.DATA_ALTERACAO = dataAtual;
            }

            try
            {
                return base.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                throw;
            }
        }


        public DbSet<tb_empresa> Banco { get; set; }





        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: fiz a alteração do código, veja se ficou mais claro.

Comment: Perfeito. Apenas senti falta do `DbSet<Empresa>`. Onde ele está? Não esqueça de implementar a interface `IEntidade` em `Empresa`.

Comment: Fiz a correção, está lá a tb_empresa é a IEntidade com os campos corretos, agora como eu posso usar estas datas de no meu EmpresaRepositorioEF?, só falta isso

Comment: Se `Empresa` implementa `TEntidade` e você colocou os dois campos de data. é só testar. Não precisa alterar o repositório. Pode colocar um *breakpoint* em `SaveChanges`, se quiser ver como funciona.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A maneira correta é colocando a atualização das datas no `SaveChanges` do contexto:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

        IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> objectStateEntries =
            from e in context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified)
            where
                e.IsRelationship == false &&
                e.Entity != null &&
                typeof(IEntidade).IsAssignableFrom(e.Entity.GetType())
            select e;

        var dataAtual = DateTime.Now;

        foreach (var entry in objectStateEntries)
        {
            dynamic entityBase = entry.Entity;

            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added || entityBase.DataCriacao == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                entityBase.DataCriacao = dataAtual;

            }

            entityBase.UltimaModificacao = dataAtual;
        }

        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Lendo o código, note que você terá que fazer seus *Models* implementarem `IEntidade`, cujo código está abaixo:

```
public interface IEntidade
{
    DateTime UltimaModificacao { get; set; }
    DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
}
```

`IEntidade` obriga seus *Models* a terem uma data de criação e uma da última modificação. Você não precisa colocar nada no *Controller*: o contexto faz tudo sozinho.

Comment: Olá Cigano, é evidente que você tem bastante conhecimento, mais as suas respostas são muito difíceis de serem entendidas é aproveitadas, quando você diz a ”maneira correta “ existem tantos padrões para desenvolvimento que esta maneira correta pode não ser tão correta.

Comment: Por que? Me explique sua dificuldade para que eu possa deixar a resposta mais acessível.

Comment: Eu fiz a alteração da minha pergunta é todo o código, onde eu poderia está ajustando o meu código de acordo com o que você esta respondendo?

Comment: Dentro da classe `Contexto`. Se `Contexto` é um `DbContext`, tem um método virtual chamado `SaveChanges`. Ou seja, minha resposta reimplementa este método. Assim, todo *Model* que implemente a interface `IEntidade` vai ser atualizado sozinho com as datas. Você não precisa escrever código pra atualizar essas datas no *Controller*. Ficou mais claro?

Comment: Eu adicionei o meu Contexto, poderia verificar como posso fazer isso?
Seu eu selecionar o DbContext é clicar em F12 eu vou ser redirecionado para o método virtual, você está se referindo a altera isso?
att

Comment: Não, não. Só colar o código todo dentro da classe `Contexto`. Depois implemente também a interface `IEntidade` dentro do diretório *Models* do seu sistema. Depois faça `Empresa` implementar `IEntidade`, assim: `public class Empresa: IEntidade`.

Comment: Ok. eu fiz o que você falou, adicionei o código final na minha resposta, esta compilando, agora como eu posso usar no EmpresaRepositorioEF? agradeço

Comment: Então, você não precisa alterar nada no repositório. Só alterar os *Models* e colocar neles a interface `IEntidade` e mais dois campos: `public DateTime UltimaModificacao { get; set; }` e `public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }`.

Comment: eu queria adicionar isso no meu EmpresaRepositorioEF, para já ficar tudo padronizado

Comment: Como eu falei, não precisa. Se repositório não precisa nem definir datas de alteração ou inclusão. O EF faz tudo sozinho. Aliás, você nem precisa implementar um repositório porque o EF já é um repositório.

Comment: Para alinhar as ideias dentro de um entendimento que seja mais fácil para mim. 
1 – Observe  o meu  EmpresaRepositorioEF : IRepositorio<tb_empresa>
2 – Ele tem um public void SalvarRegistro(tb_empresa entidade)
3 – na edição ele recebe os campos 
4 – quero adicionar as Entidades para ficar no mesmo padrão

Comment: Não precisa nada disso. Você apenas precisa implementar `IEntidade` nos *Models* em que você quer salvar as datas. Como o código já está no `SaveChanges` (e todo registro de toda entidade passa por dentro dele pra salvar), você não precisa colocar **nada** no repositório. Entendeu?

Comment: ok, não era o que eu esperava, mais tudo bem, já que não tem outro jeito, mais já foi um bom aprendizado.