# EF com herança TPT e campos de auditoria

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Olá.

Já procurei respostas nas tags de TPT e Entity mas não encontrei algo parecido.

Meu problema esta ao tentar utilizar um modelo de herança (TPT) onde as tabelas possuam campos com o mesmo nome (exemplo: `DataCadastro` e `Status`). No momento de efetuar a inclusão do registro indica o erro indicando que não aceita o campo nulo. Segue abaixo modelo:

```
public interface ICambioBase
{
    EStatus Status { get; set; }
    DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Usuário : ICambioBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public EPessoaFJ Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public short NacionalidadeId { get; set; }
    public EStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    public virtual País País { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Documento> Documentos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Telefone> Telefones { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Endereço> Endereços { get; set; }
}

public class Pessoa : Usuário
{
    public Pessoa()
    {
        Tipo = EPessoaFJ.Física;
    }
    public ESexo Sexo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public EEstadoCivil EstadoCivilId { get; set; }
}
```

Código para inserir Pessoa:

```
        Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();

        pessoa.DataNascimento = Convert.ToDateTime("03/12/1976");
        pessoa.EstadoCivilId = EEstadoCivil.Casado;
        pessoa.País = ctx.Países.Single(b => b.Sigla == "BRA");
        pessoa.Nome = "Diogenes Morais de Santana";
        pessoa.DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;
        pessoa.Status = EStatus.Ativo;
        pessoa.Sexo = ESexo.Masculino;

        ctx.Pessoas.Add(pessoa);
        ctx.SaveChanges();


    ERRO: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DataCadastro', table 'CAMBIO2001.dbo._Pessoas'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.The statement has been terminated.
```

Script Criação das Tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE _Usuários
(
    Id              INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Tipo            BIT NOT NULL, -- DOCUMENTO DE PESSOA FISICA OU JURIDICA
    Nome            VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    NacionalidadeId SMALLINT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES _Países(Id),
    Status          BIT NOT NULL,
    DataCadastro    DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE _Pessoas
(
    Id              INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES _Usuários(Id),
    Sexo            BIT NOT NULL,
    DataNascimento  DATE NOT NULL,
    EstadoCivilId   TINYINT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES _EstadosCivis(Id),
    Status          BIT NOT NULL,
    DataCadastro    DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL
);
```

Classe Contexto com override do método SaveChanges:

```
        #region Tables
    public DbSet<País> Países { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Usuário> Usuários { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Empresa> Empresas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DocumentoTipo> DocumentosTipos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Documento> Documentos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Telefone> Telefones { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Endereço> Endereços { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ParceiroFunção> TiposParceiros { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Assessor> Assessores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Apresentante> Apresentantes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClienteTipo> ClientesTipos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ocupação> Ocupações { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClienteSituação> ClientesSituações { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Banco> Bancos { get; set; }
    #endregion


    public Cotação_Contexto() : base("Cotacao_Connection")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        #region Models
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapPaíses());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapUsuários());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapPessoas());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapEmpresas());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapDocumentosTipos());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapDocumentos());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapEmails());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapTelefones());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapEndereços());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapParceirosFunções());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapAssessores());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapApresentantes());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapOcupações());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapClientesSituações());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapClientesTipos());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapClientes());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MapBancos());
        #endregion

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

        IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> objectStateEntries =
            from e in context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified)
            where
                e.IsRelationship == false &&
                e.Entity != null &&
                typeof(ICambioBase).IsAssignableFrom(e.Entity.GetType())
            select e;

        var dataAtual = DateTime.Now;

        foreach (var entry in objectStateEntries)
        {
            dynamic entityBase = entry.Entity;

            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added || entityBase.DataCriacao == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                entityBase.DataCadastro = dataAtual;
                entityBase.Status = EStatus.Ativo;
            }

        }

        //var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries();

        //foreach (var entry in entries)
        //  if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        //      foreach (var propname in entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
        //          if (propname == "DataCadastro")
        //              entry.CurrentValues["DataCadastro"] = DateTime.Now;

        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

ERRO: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DataCadastro', table 'dbo._Pessoas'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: você esta passando  pessoa.DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após alguns dias quebrando a cabeça e deixando de lado a questão de herança, retomei o modelo com a herança modificando um pequeno trecho do código.
Nas propriedade de nomes iguais adicionei uma letra indicando o nível e no mapeamento da propriedade indiquei o nome da coluna da tabela com HasCollumnName e então consegui com sucesso a inserção dos dados. Segue:

Model:

```
public abstract class Usuário
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public EPessoaFJ Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public short NacionalidadeId { get; set; }
    public EStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    public virtual País Nacionalidade { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Documento> Documentos { get; set; }
}
public class Pessoa : Usuário
{
    public ESexo Sexo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public EEstadoCivil EstadoCivilId { get; set; }
    public EStatus Statusb { get; set; } //inseri uma letra indicando o segundo nível
    public DateTime DataCadastrob { get; set; }
}
```

Mapeamentos:

```
    public MapUsuários()
    {
        this.ToTable("_Usuários");

        HasKey(u => u.Id);

        Property(u => u.Tipo)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(u => u.Nome)
            .HasMaxLength(60)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(u => u.NacionalidadeId)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(u => u.Status)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(u => u.DataCadastro)
            .IsRequired();

        HasRequired(u => u.Nacionalidade).WithMany().HasForeignKey(u => u.NacionalidadeId);

        HasMany(u => u.Documentos).WithRequired(d => d.Usuário).HasForeignKey(d => d.UsuárioId);
    }
    public MapPessoas()
    {
        this.ToTable("_Pessoas");

        HasKey(p => p.Id);

        Property(p => p.Sexo)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.DataNascimento)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.EstadoCivilId)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.Statusb)
            .HasColumnName("Status") //Indicando o nome da coluna no banco
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.DataCadastrob)
            .HasColumnName("DataCadastro")
            .IsRequired();

    }
```

Teste de inserção

```
private void btnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        País país = new País();
        país.Nome = "Brasil";
        país.Sigla = "BRA";

        ctx.Países.Add(país);

        DocumentoTipo dt = new DocumentoTipo();
        dt.Descrição = "Outros";
        dt.Tipo = EPessoaFJ.Física;

        ctx.DocumentosTipos.Add(dt);

        dt = new DocumentoTipo();
        dt.Descrição = "RG";
        dt.Tipo = EPessoaFJ.Física;

        ctx.DocumentosTipos.Add(dt);

        dt = new DocumentoTipo();
        dt.Descrição = "CNPJ";
        dt.Tipo = EPessoaFJ.Jurídica;

        ctx.DocumentosTipos.Add(dt);

        Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
        pessoa.Tipo = EPessoaFJ.Física;
        pessoa.Nome = "Diogenes Morais de Santana";
        pessoa.Nacionalidade = ctx.Países.Local.Single(p => p.Sigla == "BRA");

        pessoa.Sexo = ESexo.Masculino;
        pessoa.DataNascimento = Convert.ToDateTime("XX/XX/XX76");
        pessoa.EstadoCivilId = EEstadoCivil.Casado;
        pessoa.Statusb = EStatus.Ativo;
        pessoa.DataCadastrob = DateTime.Now;
        pessoa.Documentos = new List<Documento>();
        Documento doc = new Documento();
        doc.DocumentoTipo = ctx.DocumentosTipos.Local.Single(dtip => dtip.Descrição == "RG");
        doc.Numero = "xxxxxxxx";
        doc.DataEmissão = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2001");
        doc.Emissor = "SSP/SP";
        doc.Nacionalidade = ctx.Países.Local.Single(p => p.Sigla == "BRA");

        pessoa.Documentos.Add(doc);

        ctx.Usuários.Add(pessoa);

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Sei que não é uma solução técnica, mas resolveu meu problema.

Muito obrigado Cigano.

Comment: Na verdade este é um caso claro que o mapeamento adicional mais atrapalha que ajuda. Se você abandonasse completamente a Fluent API não teria este problema.

Answer (score 3):

Seu projeto me chama a atenção pelo não seguimento de vários padrões recomendados para o Entity Framework, a começar pelo não-uso de *Migrations*, que economiza você de gerar scripts para atualizar sua base.

A maneira correta de fazer o que você quer, quanto à data de cadastro, [é reimplementar o método `SaveChanges` no contexto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87373/gravar-data-de-inclus%C3%A3o-usando-entity-framework/87387#87387). Isso faz com que você não dependa de um construtor (que, aliás, está bem estranho no seu exemplo) e não tenha que fazer heranças desnecessárias. Para este caso, uma interface trabalha melhor, justamente porque uma classe só pode herdar uma e apenas uma classe, e se você de fato precisar herdar outra classe, terá problemas.

Outra crítica que merece especial atenção é o fato de você estar usando strings onde poderia usar `Enums`. Por exemplo:

```
pessoa.EstadoCivil = ctx.EstadosCivis.Where(ec => ec.Descrição.ToLower().Contains("casado")).Single();
```

`EstadoCivil` nem deveria ser um *Model*. Você vai fazer inserção de estados civis pouquíssimas vezes no ciclo de vida do seu sistema. Além disso, a sentença a seguir causa um ônus de performance desnecessário para a lógica de negócios.

Por último, isto:

```
pessoa.Pais = ctx.Paises.Where(b => b.Sigla == "BRA").Single();
```

Pode ser reescrito da seguinte forma:

```
pessoa.Pais = ctx.Paises.Single(b => b.Sigla == "BRA");
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas indicações. Irei efetuar as modificações sugeridas e indico se ocorreu tudo com sucesso.

Comment: Efetuei as mudanças indicadas mas o principal que é a questão da mensagem de erro permanece. Inseri o method savechanges e atualizei a propriedade DataCadastro sem sucesso.  public override int SaveChanges()
  {
   var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries();

   foreach (var entry in entries)
   {
    if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
    {
     entry.Property("DataCadastro").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
    }
   }

   return base.SaveChanges();
  }

Comment: Coloque este código na sua pergunta, por favor. Você fez um *debug* deste código pra verificar se o valor está sendo mesmo definido?

Comment: Sim, efetuei o debug e mesmo com o valor aparecendo na entidade "Pessoa" ao retornar o base.Savechanges() o erro continua. Desculpe, mas não entendi o trecho que você diz "Coloque este código na sua pergunta", você esta se referindo para eu editar minha pergunta e inserir o trecho do savechanges nela?

Comment: Isso. Exatamente. A ideia é ajudar a comunidade com sua pergunta. Quanto mais completa possível ela for, melhor.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta já com as modificações da classes e uso de Interface. Aparentemente a herança por tipo não permite que em ambas tabelas eu possua colunas com o mesmo nome.

Comment: Mas você não está usando como na resposta que coloquei como link. Desta forma não é garantido que vai funcionar. Nem teste de interface seu exemplo tem. Faça da outra forma.

Comment: Cigano. Atualizei conforme seu link, modifiquei o nome da interface e dos campos, mas mesmo assim permanece o erro. Testei também com o código comentado do método SaveChanges.

Comment: Bom, agora não sei o que pode ser. O código está correto. Só com debug e testes pra saber.